# Fastest way to clone a table minus any keys

Tags: mysql

I would like to copy data from one production table into a temporary historical store (visible for ten days then deleted) so someone can audit previous tables, as necessary. Normally I would do this with something like:

```
CREATE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

However, here I don't care about any keys (primary, foreign, whatever) and only want to optimize for speed of inserting the data. What might be the best way? The way I was thinking was to change it from InnoDB to MyISAM and then do the insert:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
ALTER TABLE new_table ENGINE = MyISAM;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table
```

Are there any faster ways?

This way took about 2m on a ~ 1M row / 1GB table:

[image]

With adding in: `ALTER TABLE new_table DISABLE KEYS;`:

[image]

And `CREATE TABLE new_table select * from old_table;`

[image]

And the fastest one (curtesy of @nbk's answer), `Create table new_table ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT * FROM old_table;`

[image]

Comment: This might be of help: https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723

Comment: @user1452962 in this case, from my testing, the export time of the table took more time than the entire time to clone the table and all data using the `SELECT *` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy everything,but loses **index** **foreign key** and **primary key**, the only think that survives is **NOT NULL**

```
Create table new_table SELECT * FROM old_table

Create table new_table3 ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT * FROM new_table
```

Comment: sure, that was my last approach and was the fastest of the three. What about `LOAD DATA INFILE` do you think that would be faster?

Comment: No, you must include the time to make an outfile prior, that will double the time costr

Comment: is there a way to `create table new_table with engine=myisam` ?

Comment: This is correct, I believe this is the fastest way CLONE TABLE'S DATA. Including data properties (like data types incl. collations), but not table properties (like keys, default collation etc). However, generated columns would be created as static.

Comment: @David542 see my changed answer

Comment: @nbk wow, that second statement is fast! Down to 17s to insert it all (see my updated question with all the results).